Looking for Teshuva from Rav Moshe Feinstein re school on xmas
I understand that Rav Moshe gave a psak in 1956 that it's required for Jewish schools to hold regular classes on Dec. 24/25.
Does anyone have a link to this teshuva?

Assuming it was written down and published in his writings. Not all of his psakim were.
